# Where can I find idle control valve on Renault Megane 2 (2005, 1.6l)

Tags: idle, stall, renault, megane

I'm having trouble keeping my engine on while on idle. First it starts of nicely, runs on idle for about 10 seconds and stalls. Next starts stall almost immediately if I don't keep the gas pedal down around 2000rpm (I can feel it trying to stall and rpm dips down but keeping the rpms high it comes back up and engine stays on). After the engine is warm, I haven't got much problem with idle. Occasionally it can stall when I press the clutch down and the rpm just drops down.

So... I'm gonna change the spark plugs next week but I'm also trying to find the idle control valve. Is it part of the throttle assembly or is it removable from it? Can't identify it. Added some photos of the engine if someone can point me to the right direction.

[image: Engine]
[image: Throttle]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The IAC can usually be found with the throttle body (TB), as it bypasses air around the butterfy(s) of the TB to provide air allowing the engine to run when you don't have your foot on the pedal. Pull the intake tract off from the TB and see if you can find it. There will be wires connected to it. I don't know if your engine is drive-by-wire (electronically controlled). If so, the motor controlling the TB could also be providing what would normally be the IAC's job, with your car not having one.